# zshell passing argument to function

Tags: scripting, zsh, zshrc

I put this in my zshrc:

```
function picofl() {
        openocd -f interface/picoprobe.cfg -f target/rp2040.cfg  -c 'program "$1" reset exit'
}
```

Then I run: `picofl myblink.elf` but it errors with unexpected argument. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get the same error when you on zsh execute VAR1=myblink.elf , followed by  openocd -f interface/picoprobe.cfg -f target/rp2040.cfg  -c 'program "$1" reset exit'"? Can you also try without the single quotes around variable name ($1)      openocd -f interface/picoprobe.cfg -f target/rp2040.cfg  -c "program $VAR1 reset exit"

Comment: Your `$1` won't be expanded because of the single quote in front of the word _program_.

Comment: @mani no hard reference works without errors

Comment: i tried "program $1 reset exit" s well with no luck thanks

Comment: for some reason i restarted my terminal and it works?!

Comment: I don't think zsh has an error message with the wording _unexpected argument_.